# (nginx + gunicorn) small server instance drops/timeouts connections on +60 simple API requests / second. Can it be improved?

Tags: django, performance, nginx, gunicorn

I'm setting up the first production architecture for my Django-based app. I'm using nginx + gunicorn + remote postgres database setup.

After performing simple API load tests with https://loader.io I've found out that when increasing the number of clients sending api requests over 60 clients/second for 30 seconds-long test the tool shows errors that the connections timeout.

When using double server setup with a load balancer I can double the clients/second number but I would expect a single 3vCPU /1 GB ram setup to be able to handle more than 30 requests/second - am I right?

I've tried a lot of differente gunicorn / nginx config parameters but nothing seems to help.

This is the content of my `/etc/nginx/nginx.conf` file:

```
user www-data;
worker_processes auto;
pid /run/nginx.pid;
worker_rlimit_nofile 100000;

events {
        worker_connections 4000;
        multi_accept on;
        use epoll;
}

http {  

        ##
        # Basic Settings
        ##

        sendfile on;
        tcp_nopush on;
        tcp_nodelay on;
        keepalive_timeout 65;
        types_hash_max_size 2048;
        server_names_hash_bucket_size 512;

        include /etc/nginx/mime.types;
        default_type application/octet-stream;

        ##
        # SSL Settings
        ##

        ssl_protocols TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2; # Dropping SSLv3, ref: POODLE
        ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;

        ##
        # Logging Settings
        ##

        access_log /var/log/nginx/access.log;
        error_log /var/log/nginx/error.log;

        ##
        # Gzip Settings
        ##

        gzip on;
        gzip_disable "msie6";

        gzip_vary on;
  gzip_types text/plain text/css application/json application/javascript text/xml application/xml application/xml+rss text/javascript;
        reset_timedout_connection on;
        keepalive_requests 100000;



       ##
        # Virtual Host Configs
        ##

        include /etc/nginx/conf.d/*.conf;
        include /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/*;
}
```

This is the content of my `/etc/nginx/sites-available/MY_DOMAIN` file:

```
server {
        listen 80;
        listen [::]:80;
        server_name MY_DOMAIN www.MY_DOMAIN;
        return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
}

server {
        listen 443 ssl;
        listen [::]:443 ssl;
        ssl on;
        client_max_body_size 5M;

        server_name MY_DOMAIN www.MY_DOMAIN;
        location = /favicon.ico { access_log off; log_not_found off; }
        location /static/ {
                root /var/www/backend;
        }
        location /loaderio-b061bddf86a67379411d4ef54f7ee430/ {
                root /var/www/backend;
        }
        location / {
                include         proxy_params;
                proxy_pass      http://unix:/var/www/backend/MY_SOCKET.sock;
        }

        location /ws/ {
                include         proxy_params;
                proxy_pass      http://unix:/var/www/backend/ws.sock;

                proxy_http_version 1.1;
                proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
                proxy_set_header Connection "upgrade";

                proxy_redirect     off;
                proxy_set_header   Host $host;
                proxy_set_header   X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
                proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
                proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-Host $server_name;
                proxy_connect_timeout       300;
                proxy_send_timeout          300;
                proxy_read_timeout          300;
                send_timeout                300;
        }
        ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/MY_DOMAIN/fullchain.pem; # managed by Certbot
        ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/MY_DOMAIN/privkey.pem; # managed by Certbot
```

This is the content of my supervisor file:

```
[program:gunicorn]
directory=/var/www/backend
command=/root/.pyenv/versions/VENV_NAME/bin/gunicorn --workers 5 --keep-alive 15 --worker-class gevent --bind unix:/var/www/backend/SOCK_NAME.sock config.wsgi:application
autostart=true
autorestart=true
log_level=debug
stderr_logfile=/var/log/gunicorn/gunicorn.out.log
stdout_logfile=/var/log/gunicorn/gunicorn.err.log
user=root
group=www-data
environment=LANG=en_US.UTF-8,LC_ALL=en_US.UTF-8

[program:daphne]
directory=/var/www/backend
command=/root/.pyenv/versions/VENV_NAME/bin/daphne -u /var/www/backend/ws.sock config.asgi:application
autostart=true
autorestart=true
stderr_logfile=/var/log/daphne/daphne.out.log
stdout_logfile=/var/log/daphne/daphne.err.log
user=root
group=www-data
environment=LANG=en_US.UTF-8,LC_ALL=en_US.UTF-8

[group:GROUP_NAME]
programs:gunicorn,daphne
```

When performing the load test the CPU vCores are between 10-18% load and the RAM  usage is around 70%

Is it possible to enhance this single server instance performance above the 60 req/sec or is it just hardware limitation (I've already tried digital ocean 16vCPU 8GB ram droplet size and the results where pretty much the same (no matter if 5 or 15 workers were used)?